# Is that possible to retrieve historical fees for crypto transactions?

Tags: python, api, bitcoin, trading, cryptocurrency

I know that it should be possible to find such data for bitcoin, but what I want is somewhat unified solution. E.g. I give a network name and timestamp - and receive something like average transaction fees for this network at that time.
I want to emulate the exchanges for the 2022 and I need to account for fees. CCXT library has `calculate_fee` method, but first of all it is not documented well, and I checked the implementation, it seems like it doesn't take any timestamp.
Any API or dataset that I could use for that?
Thanks

Tried to google any API or data and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two different types of fees: financial (from exchanges), and energy (from networks). In both cases, the fees charged will be dependent on user activity, the coins/networks used in the transactions, etc. Exchanges such as Coinbase and Binance will have more transparent information on buyer/seller fees, whereas individual coin networks (BTC, TRX) will have more variable guidance on how much your costs will be.

There's not really a straight-forward answer unless you have specific coin amounts (for networks) and trailing trading activity (for exchanges) to calculate fees, but if you search individual coin networks, you can find energy costs for transactions.

EDIT: updated the answer to distinguish between exchange and network fees.

Comment: I am not really trading, just emulating the trades. Am I getting it right, that what you are telling is exchange related fees, and that is not something I am interested in, because these are usually flat.
What I want is say sell some USDT for some BTC, in that case, there will be a transaction fee in tron network (to send funds out), and transaction fee in BTC network (to receive the funds), and that is what I am looking for

Comment: So it looks like there's two types of exchange fees: financial fees (that exchanges like Coinbase or Binance will charge), or energy fees (that networks like Tron will charge). You would probably have an easier time getting historical fees from those exchanges than ones like Tron.

Just to ask: is there a reason you want to emulate 2022 trades? Historical energy fees from a network like Tron will probably be hard to get, I'm looking into it now though.

Comment: EDIT: I wasn't able to find historical information, but I was able to find a TRX energy calculator. See below:
https://tronstation.io/calculator

Comment: I am testing my trading hypothesis, and for that I try to run the idea on the year of data, 2022 is just previous year. But great point about the calculator, even though I cannot find the data, I can build my own calculator to estimate costs. 
Thanks for the idea!